# Jquery not executing when content added after the document has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, events, bing

I use the following script to make likes on posts on a blog

```
$('.like-unlike').on('click',function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "&nbsp;Like&nbsp;") {
        postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');


        $.ajax({
            url: 'auth/classes/comments.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'token=<?php echo $token; ?>&post='+escape(postID)+'&like=yes',

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);}
        });
        $('.right#stats_'+postID).text(function (idx, text) {
            text = $.trim(text);
            var count = parseInt(text.match(/^(\d+)/), 10) || 0;
            return text.replace(/^\d+/, ++count);
        });
        $(this).html('&nbsp;Liked&nbsp;');
    }
```

i implemented a pagination script that sends requests to the server after the page has been loaded so the content is added to the page after the document has downloaded.. now my like script is not working.. if i run this script on firebug it runs ,, help please

Comment: you should have googled your title, there are hundred relative answers...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('body').on('click','.like-unlike',function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','.like-unlike',function() {
```

[Read about event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Thanks... didnt know that.. how to use $(document).ready(function(){$(".comment_box").hide();});.... in this format ? so that it hides comment_box even when its added after the document has downloaded ? –

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Change event handler to a delegated style -

```
$('body').on('click', '.like-unlike', function() {
```

Comment: Thanks... didnt know that.. how to use $(document).ready(function(){$(".comment_box").hide();});.... in this format ? so that it hides comment_box even when its added after the document has downloaded ?

Comment: No, only the visible comment boxes when the page loads will be hidden. Any others added will be shown unless you hide them again - http://jsfiddle.net/m5MnF/

Comment: is there a way i can hide all .comment_box classes even after the document has loaded ?

Comment: @user3038421: Use CSS.